# Can you transplant a bolted plant and still get viable seeds?

Tags: seeds, transplanting, seed-saving, bolting

I have a few plants in my raised beds (mostly broccoli and beets) that are bolting and producing seeds, but not ready to collect them yet.

I need the space for some new seedlings, and I don't know if I could transplant the bolting plants somewhere else and still be able to collect good seeds from them. I will definitely hurt the root system if I move them, because the few I already took out had huge roots.

Can bolted plants be transplanted or should I not bother and discard them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it somewhat depends on the stage of maturity the seeds have reached. If it was my garden I would say move them now, taking as much root as you can for each and "heel them in" as if you were handling a bare root tree that needs to be temporarily comforted before moving to its final planting location.